# I have a CSV file where some of the rows in column A are duplicate, but I need to merge the content of Column B

Tags: python, csv

The CSV file is something like:

```
NAme1; Name2
ss1; ab
ss2; abc
ss1; asq
ss3; dasda
ss2; cma
ss3; poad
```

And I want the final result to be like:

```
Name1, Name2
ss1; ab asq
ss2; abc cma
ss3; poad dasda
```

I have tried some old code, for something similar, but it did not work. Any advice?

Merging duplicated `name1` into one:

```
import csv

reader = csv.Reader(open('names.csv'))
result = {}

for row in reader:
    index = row[0]
    values = row[1:]
    if index in result:
        result[index] = [result[index][i] or v for i, v in enumerate(values)]
    else:
        result[index] = valuesimport csv

reader = csv.Reader(open('names.csv'))
result = {}

for row in reader:
    index = row[0]
    values = row[1:]
    if index in result:
        result[index] = [result[index][i] or v for i, v in enumerate(values)]
    else:
        result[index] = values
indices = []
for row in reader:
    indices.append(index)

writer = csv.writer(open('result.csv', 'w+'))
for idx in indices:
    writer.writerow([index] + result[index])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {}
with open('input.csv') as infile:
    for name,val in csv.reader(infile, delimiter=';'):
        data.setdefault(name, []).append(val)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=';')
    for name,vals in data.items():
        outfile.writerow((name, ' '.join(vals)))
```

Comment: Thank you @inspectorG4dget It worked fine, the column names disappear but I can work with that.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `pandas` to read, reshape file and save it again:

```
df = pd.read_csv('input_file.csv', sep=";")
df = df.groupby("Name1")["Name2"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x)).reset_index()
df.to_csv('output_file.csv', sep=";")
```

I assumed separator in CSV is `";"` with no extra space like `"; "`.